# Buttons in box and text resizeable

Tags: html, css

Desktop View:
[Desktop View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK9Ty.png)

Mobile View:
[Mobile View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qR5h.png)

```css
.event_item {
    background: #2b325f;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 30px;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
    height: 215px;
}

.event_item h2{margin-bottom:0;}
.event_item h6{margin-bottom:10px;}
.event_summary{display:none;}
.event_item_read p{color:#b00909;text-transform:uppercase;}

.btn-primary{
  background:#b00909 !important;
  color:white;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.btn-align {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: -20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row eventRow">
        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="events">
                                <div class="event_item">
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                     <h6>03/16/2016</h6>
                                    <h2>Just a title testing, why is this long?</h2>
                                    <p>Detroit</p>
                                    <h5 style="font-weight: bold;">7pm - 7am</h5>

                                    </div>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn-align">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary doEdit" editKey="'.$key.'"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editEvent">
                                    Edit Event
                                </button>
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary doDelete" delKey="'.$key.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteEvent">
                                    Delete Event
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
    </div>
    
    </div>
```

How would I fix this issue?

Comment: DEMO and CODE: https://jsfiddle.net/095e22s0/

Comment: @Aer0 provided the picture above. How would I fix the button that will stick like Mobile View in Desktop View. Also, how to fix the text in the box ( Desktop View) to make it looks like Mobile View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing your row class.  The column floats which collapses the container, which made you decide to add a set height, which was too short for that amount of text.  Remove the fixed height and add the `.row` class to `.event_item` and it should be fixed.

https://jsfiddle.net/19aqx97w/

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css);

.event_item {
  background: #2b325f;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin:0 0 5px 0;
}

.event_item h2{margin-bottom:0;}
.event_item h6{margin-bottom:10px;}
.event_summary{display:none;}
.event_item_read p{color:#b00909;text-transform:uppercase;}

.btn-primary{
  background:#b00909 !important;
  color:white;
  border-color: transparent;
}

.btn-align {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: -20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row eventRow">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="events">
        <div class="event_item row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h6>03/16/2016</h6>
            <h2>Just a title testing, why is this long?</h2>
            <p>Detroit</p>
            <h5 style="font-weight: bold;">7pm - 7am</h5>

          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="btn-align">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary doEdit" editKey="'.$key.'"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editEvent">
          Edit Event
        </button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary doDelete" delKey="'.$key.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deleteEvent">
          Delete Event
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Oh I understand now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

According to your comment, you want to align the buttons in your desktop view the way it is in your mobile view. You are currently using `margin-top: -20px;` on your `.btn-align` container. Remove this and your buttons will align themselves right after your content.

**EDIT:** Excuse me, I totally misunderstood you. Here should be what you actually want to achieve -> [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/095e22s0/2/)

You simply used a wrong colum-rule for your container. You did just put `col-md-4` in it while it should be `col-md-12` or empty (like you've done it for your mobile one).

By adding `col-*-12` you take the displays full width. Same goes for if you leave that empty. Since you've set up a value for `md` and not for `xs`, your `xs` was totally fine while your `md` looked a bit different. I hope now this solves your problem.

**Note:** If you want your buttons to be a bit in your event-item, you just add back your `margin-top: -20px;`. You can check my previous answer for that. Hope that helps and clarifies everything now.

Answer (score 0):

use **percentages** as that I used in the .event_item portion. Percentages will automatically adjust it.

```
.event_item {
    background: #2b325f;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5%;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin:0 0 5px 0;
    height: 70%;
}
```

Comment: That won't change anything, except of the containers height, unless you do not handle the negative margin. Simply replacing the fixed height value through a percentage one will show you that the exact same problem is still persisting.